# Proper way to bulk update with different IDs in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

For example, a table with columns of `acct`, `ip`, `status`, (`acct` is unique), there's about 1000 rows need to be updated to a specific `ip` and `status` (e.g. 11.11.11.11 and great), I noticed `update` seems to be a good choice: `Entry.objects.filter(acct=xxx).update(comments_on=False)`, but these 1000 rows all come with different `acct`, and iterating would cost too much overhead(actually there're at least 100k rows need to be updated at a time), what's a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter on any attributes, so if it's possible to write a query that describes the set of objects to update, you can use update.

```
Entry.objects.filter(attr1=yyy, attr2=zzz).update('11.11.11.11', 'great')
```

If what you have is a list of ids, you could do the following, though I don't guarantee it'll give you the performance you want:

```
Entry.objects.filter(acct__in=<list_of_accounts>).update('11.11.11.11', 'great')
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I never used `filter(acct__in=<list_of_accounts>)` before, how does it implement on SQL side? Couldn't find any docs about it, just want to check out the overhead.

Comment: If you are running the Django app locally, you can see the SQL. There is a package called django-devserver that will give you nicer output of the SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that using `filter().update()` is the only way to do it.

To increase the speed of mass operation I suggest you to wrap this bulk update into transaction:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    for acct, ip, status in accounts_to_update:
        Entry.objects.filter(acct=acct).update(ip=ip, status=status)
```

**UPDATE**: @jessamyn-smith's idea is brilliant! `acct` is unique but how about `ip`/`status` pair?  If you regroup source list by this pair will it reduce number of queries?

```
accounts_to_update = [
    ('xxx', '1.2.3.4', 'great'),
    ('xxy', '1.2.3.4', 'fail'),
    ('xxz', '1.2.3.4', 'great'),
    ('xx0', '1.2.3.0', 'great'),
]

ip_status_dict = {}
for acct, ip, status in accounts_to_update:
    accounts = ip_status_dict.setdefault((ip, status), [])
    accounts.append(acct)

with transaction.atomic():
    for (ip, status), accounts in ip_status_dict.iteritems():
        Entry.objects.filter(acct__in=accounts).update(ip=ip, status=status)
```

Comment: Thanks man! What about the overhead of `filter(acct__in=<list_of_accounts>)` line? Sorry I couldn't find any docs about it. And my cloud server has a mysql request limit, gotta make sure how many actual mysql requests take effect in it.

Comment: It will be no overhead at all! This query will be translated into `UPDATE entry SET ip='1.2.3.4', status='great' WHERE acct IN ('xxx', 'xxz')` and so on for each `ip`/`status` pair.